# Indesign - FindChangeByList exclude character style (or hyperlinks)

Tags: adobe-indesign, typography, indesign-scripting

I have a FindChangeByList search that replaces a divis between numbers with an en-dash with an 1/24 quad before and after. Unluckily it includes our Hyperlinks too and thus destroys them.

Is there a way to exclude certain character styles or even hyperlinks in general from the query?

```
grep    {findWhat:"([0-9]\\.?)\\s?[~=-]\\s?([0-9])"}    {changeTo:"$1~|~=~|$2"} {includeFootnotes:true, includeMasterPages:true, includeHiddenLayers:true, wholeWord:false}
```